# Will an IIS SelfSSL certificate still be valid when the signing server is replaced?

Tags: active-directory, ssl-certificate, certificate, 802.1, self-signed-certificate

Will my 10 year valid self-signed certificate, that is using a common name not resembling any hostname, still be valid/trusted by others in the AD, after the signing server is replaced in maybe a few years?
It will be used for 802.1x authentication.

I think yes, as it is being deployed via GPO to all clients, but I'd like some expert opinion on this please.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying the self signed certificate into a Trusted container in the user's or computer's local store via GPO then yes it will be valid.